# mathematic statistical library for PHP

Tags: php, statistics

I wonder, if there is a library for statistical tests like

- t-test
- Anova test
- Kolmogorov Smirnov
  etc.....
  for PHP?

I found a pecl extension: http://php.net/manual/de/book.stats.php , which gives some basic parameters, but no tests found yet

Comment: Have you looked into using R (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language) and just accessing it with PHP using rCurl? (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/index.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a full PHP library you can have a look [here](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2004/07/22/php_anova.html), but I don't know if it is something really good.

This statistical test is quite gready and I don't know if php is a good choice to compute it. As proposed in the comments, you should write your script in R language and then call it.
There are two ways to call another language depending on your server architecture. Assuming you will have only one server, you can use [proc_open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) :

```
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),  //a pipe where you will read
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),  //std out : a pipe where you will write
   2 => array("file", "/tmp/error-output.txt", "a") // stderr : a log file, not mandatory here
);
 $pipes = array();
$process = proc_open('R yourfile.r',$decriptorspec,$pipes);

fwrite($pipes[0],$yourStatsToBeCompute);
$result = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
fclose($pipes[0]);
fclose($pipes[1]);
proc_close($process);
```

You can also use cURL to contact a Rscript on another server with RCurl.